# is there a way prevent backflow from my sink?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sewer

I have a downstairs condo with plumbing issues.  I get re-occuring backflow out of my sink that looks to be my neighbors sewage from their kitchen sink (we share sink lines down to the main drain).  Worse of all once this starts occuring I get continual backflow of the neighbors sewage directly out into my sink which can flood my kitchen until the lines get cleared by a plumbing machine. Plumber says whatever the issue is its beyond the pipes in my unit.
So my question is, is there something I can reasonably do to atleast prevent massive backflow out of my kitchen sink when this occurs?

Comment: The most reasonable thing you can do is call your landlord or condo management and tell them to fix this, as it's occurring in the shared plumbing outside of your unit and therefore not your responsibility...

Comment: put a valve on your drain pipe. if you had a plummer out there and he said it will keep happening. when this does happen just close the valve

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, we can get 'HepVo' waterless valves which are intended to be used instead of a P-trap.  These - the manufacturer claims - are good resisting high backflow pressures.  If you installed one of these or a similar non-return valve, it would prevent the flooding.

You'd still have the root problem - and your sink would not drain when the pipes are blocked - but at least you'd not get waste water in your sink.

You should encourage your neighbours to make sure that their own kitchen waste is properly vented and running freely too.  It might be that a bit of preemptive chemical maintenance (by them and/or you) on a routine basis would keep problems at bay for longer.